# How do i solve PermissionError: [WinError 32] when renaming files with PyPDF2? Stay tuned, .close() is not the answer

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm starting with python and i have a small problem. I'm trying to code a application to rename a file in a folder.

I'm gettning the following error when i run the program: PermissionError: [WinError 32] File is being used by another process
I belive this is happening becouse the file is still being accessed by IDE, but i can't figure out how to stop it from doing so. Every post i've read about the problem this error recomends using .close(), but this doesn't solve the problem.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import os

local_doc = input(r"Onde está o arquivo?") 
os.chdir(local_doc)                        

def n_folhas(localdoc,x):
    integral = os.listdir(local_doc)[x] 
    reader = PdfFileReader(integral)
    folhas = reader.getNumPages()
    return(folhas)

folhas = n_folhas(local_doc,0)

print (folhas)

os.listdir(local_doc)[0]
os.rename(local_doc, "CÓPIA INTEGRAL. FLS. 1 A "+str(folhas)+'.pdf')
```

Sorry about the language and the code being a mess, it's my first actual code.

Thank you, have a great day!

Comment: (1) I assume you are using absolute references? Because you are asking for the location of a directory, moving into that directory, and calling that directory again in your function. At that point your PDF would be in your current working folder. (2) Note that the second time you call `os.listdir(local_doc)[0]` you aren't doing anything with it - did you mean to get the filename again like you did in the function?

Comment: (3) Finally - and most importantly in context of your error - you are using `os.rename` but the code is wrong. The function header is ` os.rename(src, dst, *, src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)`. This means you are passing *the directory* and asking it to be renamed to the destination filename. And remember, this is the directory you have moved into - which means it will be in use, because you're working in it!

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in full.

As per my comments, there are a number of problems with the code, but the main issue is that you are calling `os.rename` incorrectly and trying to rename your current working folder, which Windows is correctly pointing out is in use.

*Note for future learning:* please take a look at `Pathlib`and `f strings`. `Pathlib` is the more modern Python method of handling file and folder objects. `f strings` are the more up-to-date way of including variables and expressions in dynamic strings.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import os

# Get the location of the PDF
# Also current working directory in case we need to switch back
local_doc = input(r"Onde está o arquivo?")
start_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(local_doc)

# Get all the PDF files inside the given location
list_of_pdf = [ pdf_file for pdf_file in os.listdir() if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf") ]

# We have the list of files, only need to give the function
# the specific file
def n_folhas(integral):
    reader = PdfFileReader(integral)
    folhas = reader.getNumPages()
    os.rename(integral, f"CÓPIA INTEGRAL. FLS. 1 A {str(folhas)}.pdf")
    return

# Call the function and give it the 
# first file from the list of PDF files
n_folhas(list_of_pdf[0])
```